# What is the meaning of "b+-" in Python codes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following lines of code:

```
plt.plot(history_LSTM.history['loss'], "b+-", label='training', 
        color = "red")
plt.plot(history_LSTM.history['val_loss'], "b+-", label='validation', 
        color = "blue")
```

Could anyone tell me please what is the meaning of `b+-` in these lines of code? and what is their use?

Comment: In both cases, that is a string which is used as the second argument to that `plot` function

Comment: It's not built-in Python, it's part of the library that you are using, which looks like matplotlib.pyplot: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, here "b+-" means :

b: This specifies the color of the line -> blue in this case

+: This specifies that markers should be placed at each data point, and in this case it will (+)

-: This specifies that the line should be solid.